# How to Linq to yml

Tags: .net, linq, yaml

I want to query a specific node of a `yaml` file.I already know about `YamlDotNet`, but even if it can do it, I don't know how.

**Given** the following file:

`version: '3.5'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: localRegistry.com:443/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka-broker-1:
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-broker-1
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PROTOCOL_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9094
      KAFKA_PROTOCOL_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_PORT: 9092
      # ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 30000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

**When** I query the image

**Then** the value of the `image` tags under each service should be returned
**And** if the `image` tag does not exist the name of the service (like `zookeeper` and `kafka-broker-1` here) should be returned instead.

**Notice** that the `services` tag is constant, the name of each service (like `zookeeper` here) and the image are variables

So how can I query a `yaml` file in `dotnet`?

Comment: There is no IQueryable provider for YamlDotNet. You would have to just deserialize the whole yaml file and do the querying in memory.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic: I have a set of variable items under a certain node and I need to get the children of the constant node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution to your problem. Not too performant since i'm using dynamic and searching the list twice but it gets the job done. With YamlDotNet.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testYaml = @"
        version: '3.5'
        services:
            zookeeper:
                image: localRegistry.com:443/zookeeper
                ports:
                    - ""2181:2181""
            kafka-broker-1:
                depends_on:
                    - zookeeper
                ports:
                    - target: 9094
                      published: 9094
                      protocol: tcp
                      mode: host
                environment:
                    # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-broker-1
                    HOSTNAME_COMMAND: ""docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2""
                    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
                    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
                    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PROTOCOL_NAME: OUTSIDE
                    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9094
                    KAFKA_PROTOCOL_NAME: INSIDE
                    KAFKA_PORT: 9092
                    # ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 30000
                volumes:
                    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock";

        var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
            .WithNamingConvention(new CamelCaseNamingConvention())
            .Build();

        var deserialized = deserializer.Deserialize<YamlClass>(testYaml);

        var withImageTagValues = deserialized.Services
            .Where(x => x.Value.ContainsKey("image"))
            .Select(x => x.Value["image"]);

        var withoutImageTagValues = deserialized.Services
            .Where(x => !x.Value.ContainsKey("image"))
            .Select(x => x.Key);

        var result = withImageTagValues.Concat(withoutImageTagValues);

        foreach(var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
    }
}

class YamlClass
{
    public string Version { get;set;}

    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Services { get;set; }
}
```